# NSURL prints twice when sharing through UIActivityView

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, uiactivityviewcontroller

Here is my code

```
let myURL = URL(string: "http://www.dwz.cn/BabySmarter")
let shareActivity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myURL!, "我的宝宝比\(String(describing: Int(finalScore!)))% 的宝宝更发展！你的呢?"], applicationActivities: nil)
shareActivity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(shareActivity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result Image]

This has to be a glitch. Or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: where/when/how is this output shown?

Answer (score 0):

May be problem with URL , you can pass url as string.

```
let shareActivity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["http://www.dwz.cn/BabySmarter 我的宝宝比\(String(describing: Int(finalScore!)))% 的宝宝更发展！你的呢?"], applicationActivities: nil)
shareActivity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(shareActivity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I would like to pass the URL as a string, but I can't because most users in China share via WeChat, and WeChat will not accept text only for some reason. It says, "Unable to share content." So I need the NSURL for WeChat to accept it as sharable content.

Comment: @SomeGuy run your code. url at end occurs only when you copy from activity, while sharing its does not appear twice.